# How to deploy only an affected nx service to GCP APP Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Given that I have an NX application with multiple services, and I want to do continuous deployment of only affected service/s to App Engine, how can I point to a given **service.yaml** (or multiple) within the common **cloudbuild.yaml** for the project?
Each service in the monorepo has its own service.yaml as describe [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files#examples)
ex:
My **cloudbuild.yaml** looks like:

```
steps:
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'affected:build']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 'dist/apps/express-app-1/service.yaml']
  timeout: '1600s'
```

In my code I am pointing to specific service which is hard-coded but I need it to depend on `nx affected:build`.

Is there a way to do that, and to achieve continuous deployment with `nx build:affected` and Cloud Build triggers?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: Did you get this working?
I'm trying to deploy my Nx backend app (Nx app=nodjs+nestjs) to gcloud, but I can't get it working:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605444/cant-deploy-my-back-end-api-from-an-nx-workspace-to-google-cloud

Answer (score 1):

From what I read so far there is no standardised or "official-the-NX" way of doing such things (yet).

Have a look here in this [discussion](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/discussions/9183). It was the best "answer" I found for myself, so far...

Maybe a quick and simple tip:

You could consume the output of [`print-affected`](https://nx.dev/cli/print-affected) in your CI in order to decide which apps need to be built / deployed.

`npx nx print-affected --type=app --select=projects`